# ReSharper C++ 1.1 not working with auto key word

Tags: c++, resharper, resharper-c++

I'm using ReShaper C++ 1.1. If I use auto to create an vector I do not get any code completion. Below is the code:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    // no code completion
    auto result = vector<string>{};
    // if I do this I get code completion
    vector<string> list = vector<string>{};
    auto word = string{};
}
```

Is this a bug in ReSharper C++ 1.1?

Comment: I assume you mean `C++11` not `C++1.1`. Are you giving your compiler the correct flag to turn on `C++11`? Also did you include the vector's header? Is that all your code?

Comment: @Galik I'm talking about "Reshaper C++ 1.1" it's a newer product from JetBrains. But my Intel compiler has the correct flag to use C++11, and the vector header is included in the percompiled header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-15192), but we've already fixed it.

Comment: Yep. I'm the one that reported it.